# Need a single instance but not through singleton

Tags: class, singleton, instance

I have a problem here. I have two Classes A and B. Class A Consumes Class B and We don't want any other class to create an instance of Class B. Only Class A have access to create the instance of Class B.

And at same time, I don't want singleton instance of B and I don't want to define Class B inside Class A.

Any help.

Thanks in advance.

-Harsha

Comment: Is this C++ or is it Java, or some other object-oriented language?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem, but you could just define class B in the same .cpp file as class A, so no other class would even see the definition and therefore cannot create an instance of class B, e.g.

a.hpp

```
class B;

class A {
    B *b;
    A();
    ...
};
```

a.cpp

```
#include <a.hpp>

class B
{
    ...
};

A::A()
{
    b = new B();
}

A::~A()
{
    delete B;
}
```

If you want class B to be in a separate file, you could put it into b.cpp and include this file in a.cpp.
You could also make the constructor of B private and use [friend classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).